# Regex to match the data between the double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below  strings

```
1. "Settings Icon": "xxhdjxxx7wn"
2. "Settings Icon": "afewfwl"
3. "Settings Icon": "fdj ssde"
```

I want the regex to match all these strings by ignoring the content in right side of colon

I have `(['"])(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*\1` which matches with content inside double quote. But couldn't solve above case.. Please help

Comment: Something like `"(.*)":`, just take Group 1 it should give you the left side.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you're question correctly, you only want the string within the quotes, from the left side of the colon. Is that correct?  If so, this might work for you:

```
(['"])([^\1]*?)\1:.*$
```

For this expression, capture group 2 will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
const string = `1. "Settings Icon": "xxhdjxxx7wn"
2. "Settings Icon": "afewfwl"
3. "Settings Icon": "fdj ssde"`

console.log( string.match(/(?<=")[^"]+(?=":)/g) )
```

**DEMO**

[image]

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ":                       '":'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/H6C7ZL/1).